# Recursive Sequential Search for Linked List Output Error

Tags: c++11, recursion, search, linked-list, boolean

So my professor would like us to design recursive functions for a linked list from this class 'addressBookType' which is derived from 4 other classes. The program basically creates an address book with the person's name, address, date, and relationship, each of those has their own classes.

The recursive functions she wants to make are a print, append, delete, and sequential search.

I've made all of them recursive except for the sequential search function.

Here is the original and the recursive version:

```
bool addressBookType::seqSearch(extPersonType item) const
{
    bool found = false;
    ListNode *nodePtr; // pointer to traverse the list

    nodePtr = head; // start the search at the first node

    found = seqSearchRecursive(nodePtr, item); // call recursive function

    if(found)
        found = (nodePtr->value == item); // test for equality

    return found;
}

bool addressBookType::seqSearchRecursive(ListNode *nPtr, extPersonType obj) const
{
    if(nPtr == NULL) // return false if value not found
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(nPtr->value == obj) // return true if object found
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        seqSearchRecursive(nPtr->next, obj); // call recursive funct with next value
}
```

My problem is that I get an output error. When I deleted an object from the list and searched for it, it returned `false`. Then I searched for an object in the list and it returned `false`. So something is making the function always come back false.. anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have forgotten a `return` keyword in `else` block. So `seqSearchRecursive` is called but its result is unused and function reaches the end without returning anything, which is considered [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) for non-void function. You can use `-Wall` and `-Wextra` compiler flags to get notified about such problems.

I can also advice passing `obj` as `const extPersonType& obj` if `extPersonType` is not an alias to basic type. And since c++11 a [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/nullptr) is preferred over `NULL`.

Comment: Do you mean when I call it in this statement? `found = seqSearch(nodePtr, item)` Or the else statement in the recursive function? I tried adding return statements in the that else statement, and no luck. @Dmitry